# How to add jitter to a d3 plot?

Tags: d3.js, label

I'm trying to plot points and adding them jitter. The points have text labels, so once I compute the jittered point position, I'd like to save it and use it for the text label. I was thinking of adding a new jitter attribute to each point and then using it to set cx (points) and x (labels):

```
# compute the jittered positions
points.attr("x_jitter", function (d){
    return x_scale(d.x) + my_random_jitter_function()
});    
# set them to the points and the labels
points.attr("cx", function (d, i){
    return points.attr("x_jitter")
});
text_labels.attr("x", function(d, i){
    return points.attr("x_jitter")
});
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: You could put points and labels in a `g` element and add the jitter to that without having to store it.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff That's pretty elegant! I can add them to a g element and translate them using `x_jitter`. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would just do

```
points.each(function(d,i) {
  d.jitter = xscale(d.x) + random_jitter();
})
points.attr("cx", function(d,i) { return d.jitter });
text_labels.attr("x", function(d,i) { return d.jitter });
```