# How to detect overlapping dots in a scatter plot using D3?

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, scatter-plot, overlapping

I am creating a scatter plot with D3 but I noticed that several dots are overlapping in the same spot. Since every data point is meaningful, so I want to indicate that there are several dots in that place. So I think the first thing I need to do is to detect whether there is overlapping happening when drawing the scatter plot.

What I have in mind is that, when I use the following code to append circles in svg, I will keep every pair of the (cx, cy) values in an array and when drawing the next dot, go through the array to see whether that (cx, cy) pair has exist, if so there has been a dot already. And I can do something to indicate there is overlapping.

```
var starterCircle = starterItem.append("circle")
    .attr("class", "dot starter circle-default")
    .attr("r", 6)
    .attr("cx", function(d) {
        if (getXSelectedOption() == "MP") {
            return calcMinutesPlayed(d, "x");
        }
        else {
            return xScale(d[getXSelectedOption()]);
        }
     })
     .attr("cy", function(d) { 
        if (getYSelectedOption() == "MP") {
            return calcMinutesPlayed(d, "y");
        }
        else {
            return yScale(d[getYSelectedOption()]);
        }
     });
```

But it seems to me that it takes lots of calculation to do that and I was wondering whether there is simpler way to deal with that.

Any suggestions will be appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: You could take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17093922/how-to-add-jitter-to-a-d3-plot

Comment: One way of doing it would be to simply make the dots partly transparent. This way you'll see where dots overlap because this part will be less transparent.

Answer (score 2):

How about create a matrix m(SX, SY), where SX and SY are the size of the 2d plot. When you add a new data point (cx, cy), mark it down in the matrix entry m(cx, cy). Then you will know the number of overlap data points you have at point (cx, cy).

Answer (score 1):

There are a few approaches that are used in D3js to detect "collisions". These usually follow the approach of force layouts. `d3.layout.force()` also see, `d3.forceCollide([radius])`.

This example shows basic principles: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3231298

This example show a method to detect and move overlapping circles on a graph: http://bl.ocks.org/ericandrewlewis/dc79d22c74b8046a5512