# Jittering geo paths using D3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, geo

I'm trying to add 'jitter' or add random noise to a D3.js map that contains line features. Note, this is slightly different from this [other example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17093922/how-to-add-jitter-to-a-d3-plot) because it involves geo paths. Additionally, while I'd like to use a custom transformation to do this, I don't think I can because I need to be able to use a standard transformation (from WGS84 to NY State Plane). I think the jittering function should either be based on a modified `path` function, or be a separate function which takes a `path` as input.

```
var projection = d3.geo.conicConformal()
      .parallels([40 + 40 / 60, 41 + 2 / 60])
      .rotate([74, -40 - 10 / 60]);

var path = d3.geo.path()
    .projection(projection);
```

Note that I don't really want to modify the input data at all (i.e., the jittering should be on the paths, not the input geodata). Note also that the jittering can be totally random (i.e., it does not have to be the same every time). My initial thought is to wrap the data in a jitter function, or to wrap the path function in a jitter function. Either way, I'm not really sure where to start on this? Any suggestions? Even a link to the relevant API item would be awesome!

```
svg.selectAll("path")
    .data(jitter(lines.features)) // Wrap data in jitter function... or...
  .enter().append("path")
    .attr("class", "line")
    .attr("d", function(d) { return jitter(path(d)); })  // Jitter path directly
```

A (simplified) [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0weqod5v/2/) is available here for reference.

Comment: I think the question you've linked to is still relevant for the way that you've currently set it up. `path` returns the projected path (i.e. an SVG path in screen coordinates) that you could jitter using that method. It's completely independent of any projection you're applying before that.

Comment: Thanks @LarsKotthoff. I see what you are saying, and this makes sense. However, I'm not quite sure how to get there: I'm not sure now to access the individual points of a `path` in order to jitter them... Any pointers on that one?

Comment: Unfortunately, this isn't straightforward (see e.g. [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11503151/in-d3-how-to-get-the-interpolated-line-data-from-a-svg-line)). I would get the unprojected points from the geometry of the feature, project them, and then jitter each one.

Comment: Ok, so it looks like this is likely the solution I need: https://gist.github.com/mbostock/5663666, but I can't figure out how to use this in conjunction with an existing `d3.geo` projection (such as `d3.geo.conicConformal`). Any thoughts out there?